# ci) - also delete the surrounding parens?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I use `ci)` and `ci]` quite a lot to change what happens in between the parens or brackets.

Is there a way to remove everything *including* the parens or brackets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `a` variant: `ca)`, `ca]`.

The `i` is "inner", whereas the `a` is for "a" as in "a word", "a sentence", or "a [] block". I usually think of these as "inner" and "outer" ("auter?") though.

See `:help text-objects` for a full list and documentation, or `:help objects` for a brief overview.

Comment: The version that sticks well in my head is that `ci)` is "change inside brackets" and `ca)` is "change around brackets"

Comment: Amazing! this is a game changer. Thank you

Comment: note that di(, da(, yi( and ya( etc. also work and are also extremely useful